# Windows resize with aspect ratio, doesn't work on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, winapi, user-interface, resize, window-resize

I have always used the following code, to implement a ratio resize in Windows:

```
    case WM_SIZING:
    {
        //
        // Implements ratio resize.
        //
        if (window->is_internal_flag_set(Window::kWindowHasAspectRatio))
        {
            RECT * rect = (RECT *)lparam;
            double ratio = window->get_window_aspect_ratio();
            int adjusted_h;

            switch (wparam)
            {
                case WMSZ_BOTTOMRIGHT:
                case WMSZ_BOTTOMLEFT:
                case WMSZ_RIGHT:
                case WMSZ_LEFT:
                {
                    adjusted_h = (int)((double)window->m_frame_rect.width() / ratio);
                    rect->bottom = rect->top + adjusted_h + window->m_diff_y;
                    return 0;
                }
                case WMSZ_TOPLEFT:
                case WMSZ_TOPRIGHT:
                {
                    adjusted_h = (int)((double)window->m_frame_rect.width() / ratio);
                    rect->top = rect->bottom - adjusted_h - window->m_diff_y;
                    return 0;
                }
                case WMSZ_TOP:
                case WMSZ_BOTTOM:
                {
                    int adjusted_w = (int)((double)window->m_frame_rect.height() * ratio);
                    rect->right = rect->left + adjusted_w + window->m_diff_x;
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

This code works perfectly in Windows XP, and Windows 7 as well.
I couldn't try this on Windows 8.x, but now I'm on Windows Server 2012, and this simply doesn't work.
Windows Server 2012 calls the window's dispatcher function with the proper `WM_SIZING` message, but it simply ignores the rectangle I "give" through `lparam`.
However, some strange aspect ratios do happen, for example when I resize the window only from the bottom side, when I release the mouse Windows will set a kind of aspect ratio, but with is totally wrong.

What is wrong with this code? Why I have problems only on Windows Server 2012?

NOTE: for the sake of brevity I have omitted the code of the `Window` class you see there. Its quite straightforward to understand the code anyway.

Comment: What on Earth is m_diff_x/y?

Comment: That's just something irrelevant. It is needed to calculate the difference of the window's border, and adjust the window size accordingly.

Comment: The docs say "An application should return TRUE if it processes this message" and yet you are returning 0. Maybe Server 2012 enforces that?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the problem. I already tried to return TRUE there, but still it doesn't work on Windows Server 2012